# Get all non null column count in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table columns are `a (int), b (int), c (int)`. And also I have too many rows in this table. For example I have 10 rows in that table. I want to get my column count which not null.

In example

[image]

So my result will be 6. So how can I get null columns count in T-SQL ?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the results that you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a count of all the values across the columns:

```
select count(a) + count(b) + count(c) as NonNullCount,
       3*count(*) - (count(a) + count(b) + count(c)) as NullCount
from table t;
```

This should give you the "6" and "3" that you specify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Query below would give you count of any not null value:

```
SELECT COUNT(a)+COUNT(b)+COUNT(c) 
  FROM yourtable
```